# Android resource compilation failed when debug to device

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some problem, when I debug my code to device. the error show like this :

```
Android resource compilation failed
/Users/agungnugroho/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects/Version 3.0/hris/
app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/
values/values.xml:4: error: unknown tag <:string>.
/Users/agungnugroho/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects/Version 3.0/
hris/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/
merged.dir/values/values.xml:5: error: unknown tag <:string>.
/Users/agungnugroho/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects/Version 3.0/
hris/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/
merged.dir/values/values.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

It happen when I add library and here my **build.gradle** code :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id.co.poslogistics.hris"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Can anyone help me please, because I don't understand what that error?

Comment: Please attach your values.xml

Comment: The tags in your `values.xml` file should start with `<string>`, not `<:string>`

Comment: thanks, its work. i just delete all of my <string> than create again @ReazMurshed

Comment: Great to know that helped. Putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags in your `values.xml` file should start with `<string>`, not `<:string>`.

Answer (score 0):

i check my **value.xml** becauce there was a wrong call method